# Equine sound effects

Tags: word-request

Subtitled movies sometimes have that nice feature, where important sounds and background noise are written out in words, something which you could not learn from just the audio.

In this way I understood that horses can neigh, whinny, snort, snicker, *hooves*, and whatnot.

There is that one sound that, if a human made it, we would call "blowing raspberries". Horses frequently do that in movies, but I found no consistent subtitling for that sound. Research on https://dict.leo.org finds discussions, but no clear answer. Wikipedia entries mention all sounds, but do not describe it in a way that would allow a clear assignment. Especially the distinction between neighing and whinnying seems to be blurry, my impression is that neither would match.

Comment: Horses also **nicker**, which is to produce a breathy rumbling sound.

Comment: BTW, the term for these sounds animals make to communicate is **vocalization**.  The word **sound-effects** refers to *imitations* of such sounds.  Movie sound studios can provide a wide variety of sound-effects, for example, the sound of galloping hooves or of a display window breaking.

Comment: Horses Make 8 Sounds To Convey Information, Moods http://www.mackinacislandnews.com/news/2005-07-09/Columnist/067.html - Horse communication https://www.learn-about-horses.com/horse-communication.html/

Comment: Horses make that "blowing a raspberry" sound by vibrating their nostrils, so it could be called a **snort**.

Comment: Where sub-titles are concerned, though there may be many terms or phrases that could be applied in any given situation, the sub-titler will normally choose a simple word to convey a sound-effect. Their job is to enable the viewer/reader to concentrate on the on-screen action. Of course there will always be exceptions, but sound-effects are typically less critical than dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

The "blowing raspberries" sound that horses make can be called a *snort*

> The stallion **snorted** and pawed the ground as the cowboy approached slowly, swinging his lariat.

I don't know why snorts are not subtitled, but it would be perfectly natural to do so.

There is little difference between a *neigh* and a *whinny*.  As with most onomatopoeia, the words are spelled like the sounds, so it's really up to you to choose which you want to use to describe any particular horsey sound.